# Connect to Flask from Virtualbox Guest using NAT

Tags: networking, flask, virtualbox, port, nat

I'm making a client-server app and i would make my flask server on my host and the client on a virtualbox machine .

I've made the Flask host as that

```
app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

But when i try to connect from firefox on virtualbox to `0.0.0.0:5000` or `127.0.0.1:5000` I get `"Unable to connect"` Message .

I'm using NAT network , i've forwarded the *5000 HOST ==> 5000 Guest* .

Still have the same problem .

- My Host machine : MacOS
- My Guest Machine : Ubuntu 16.04

*PS:*

- The server is working fine on the host machine
- I've tried the bridge network and it's working (i connect using my host ip instead of 0.0.0.0 ) , but i want do it with NAT because i've
  many ports to forward and because it's reliable for my project .

Comment: "_i want do it with NAT because i've many ports to forward and because it's reliable for my project._ You only need to forward ports with NAT. Directly connecting doesn't require forwarding of ports.

Comment: I've forwarded ports with NAT ( From 5000 to 5000 ) but i got Unable to connect

Comment: NAT is a kludge that you only use if you really, really must, e.g. a privately addressed network connecting to the public Internet. If you do not use NAT, then you don't forward ports, and everything works the way IP was designed to work.

Comment: I've fixed that on the NAT by connecting to flask using my host ip , but the problem is that i must change it every time when the router changes the ip , so , is there an alternative for that ?

Comment: Servers, which is what you have, should have a fixed address. You could statically set it, or you could create a DHCP reservation to give it the same address every time. You could also use DNS to translate a name to the address.